# Custom OAuth2 user database

Tags: php, database, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm currently implementing OAuth2 in my website to keep an user logged in inside an Android app. I want to change the default OAuth2 user database to my own user database. Unfortunately I can't find out how to do that. It should be possible with overriding classes and without changing the code in the core library, but how to do it?

This is what I have in my `server.php` file:

```
// Autoloading (composer is preferred, but for this example let's just do this)
require_once('/src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
OAuth2\Autoloader::register();

$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => 'mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx', 'username' => 'xxxx', 'password' => 'xxxx'));

// Pass a storage object or array of storage objects to the OAuth2 server class
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);

// Add the "Password / User Credentials" grant type
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($storage));
```

So here I want to use to my own user table instead of the default `oauth_users` table. And because the passwords are salted I need to have a different password check too. I am using the BShaffer OAuth2 Library: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php

Comment: Hi, I have the same question you got any answer?

Answer (score 1):

With this library it's easy to write custom code so you don't have to touch the core of this library.
For this problem you'll have to create a custom storage class that implements the [UserCredentialsInterface](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Storage/UserCredentialsInterface.php). There are two methods in here which you need to implement yourself

```
public function checkUserCredentials()

public function getUserDetails()
```

Here you can implement your logic for checking user details and fetching user details.
After this you'll need to add this storage to the oAuth server like this:

```
$server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);
$userStorage = new YourCustomUserStorage();
$server->addStorage($userStorage, 'user_credentials');
```

You'll also need to pass this storage to any Grant type you're adding to the server, in your case it looks like this:

```
$server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\UserCredentials($userStorage));
```